# Chrome Extension : Save authorization header value (token) to a local file or pass it to background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension, http-headers, authorization

I am fairly new to developing chrome extensions.. my objective is to save the authorization header value after logging into some public site that runs on oauth2 authentication. Assume auto sign-in is enabled. Once the page is loaded can I save the auth header value into a local file through chrome extension. Enabling "Allow access to file URLs" is ok. If for security reasons saving to file is not allowed.. atleast I'd like to pass this value to background page. Appreciate if someone can provide an example or a link that explains the similar scenario.
I tried but there is a huge amount of information in the web and unable to find a good sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry can't add code now but these are my 2 cents:

Forget saving to a file, you still have many options to save the token: chrome.storage (what I use), local.storage, indexedDB, a cookie.

The token you want to fetch from the header of an HTTP response is also probably cached into a cookie by the browser, so what you need is probably using the chrome extension cookie api to get it instead of intercepting it on the web request itself.

Passing messages between background script and other scripts is done via the message api.